# What is the meaning of se_*** prefix in LIO SCSI Target code base

Tags: linux-kernel, scsi

[LIO](http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/LIO) code base is scattered w/ a lot of constructs prefixed w/ **se** (e.g. se_cmd, se_session etc.)

What is the meaning of this **se** prefix ? (I've failed to find some comment about it in LIO kernel code base)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It came from "Storage Engine" term which is used widely in LIO.

> In addition to modularizing the transport protocol used for carrying
>   SCSI commands ("fabrics"), the Linux kernel target, LIO, also
>   modularizes the actual data storage as well. These are referred to as
>   "backstores" or "storage engines". The target comes with backstores
>   that allow a file, a block device, RAM, or another SCSI device to be used 
>   for the local storage needed for the exported SCSI LUN. Like the rest
>   of LIO, these are implemented entirely as kernel code.